# Permissions to add member to group via Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to add a member via this MS Graph API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http but am running into permission issues. The request returns back

```
 "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
 "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."
```

I am able to call APIs like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http with no permission problem, and I have Group.ReadWrite.All and User.ReadBasic.All permissions. Is there a special permission or role I need to be to call this API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you also need `GroupMember.ReadWrite.All` and `Directory.ReadWrite.All` `Application` permission.

[image]

***`PostMan Request URL:`***

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/93d96b98-YourGroupId_3ede399/members/$ref`

***`PostMan Request Body:`***

```
{
 "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/b33ce735_YourUserId_15337c469076"
}
```

**`Postman Test:`**

[image]

**`Added On Group:`**
[image]

> **Note:** Make sure after adding permission you have accepted grant admin consent.

Please refer to [Official Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: I have `Directory.ReadWrite.All` as well. How can I get `GroupMember.ReadWrite.All` permission? It does not show up in the permissions list when I go to 'Modify Permissions' on Graph Explorer. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoYTQ.png.

Comment: Yes it does. You can add in on azure portal. Or can check your permission on [https://jwt.io/](https://jwt.io/)

Comment: Sorry if this is going off topic but what are delegated permissions? I see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference) that Microsoft Account is not supported for `GroupMember.ReadWrite.All` delegated permission. Not sure if that is relevant to my situation?

Comment: No problem, delegated permission is request for sign in user only(Once the user authenticated). you just make sure this `Directory.ReadWrite.All`  permission would be work successfully. Application permission is alright for your case.

Comment: Is there documentation on adding permissions in Azure Portal? Btw, I am using a @microsoft.com account.

Comment: No personal account is not supported. You have to use azure tenant account.  Also make sure your token is in correct format.

Comment: Well that's not helping me one bit... Have added the permissions and yet I'm still getting the "insufficient privileges" error.

Comment: Did you added the admin consent? If you alread did that in that case could you please open a new question with your issue so that it can be investigate further, I think this context is different than you.

Comment: Welp. I've added the groups, all have admin consent granted, still also getting the same error as @Ortund indicating that I don't have permission to add the user to the group.

Comment: Would you kindly post new question along with your steps so that can be investigate seperately thanks.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron done https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71739195/adding-guest-user-to-azure-ad-group-fails-with-correct-permissions-set

Comment: Hello @MdFaridUddinKiron , I followed your steps on this so thank you. However, I am confused about the $ref part. Should I directly use it or does this variable have some values defined? I am getting this error: `405 Method Not Allowed` response: {"error":{"code":"Request_BadRequest","message":"Specified HTTP method is not allowed for the request target.","innerErr (truncated...)

Comment: Could you please post a new question to make that issue different than this. That might be investigate there.