# 'Insufficient privileges to complete the operation' when trying to create group via Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, msal.js

**Desired Behaviour**

Create a `group` via Microsoft Graph, using the JavaScript SDK and MSAL in a `single tenant application` with `delegated` API permissions.

**Actual Behaviour**

```
{
  "statusCode": 403,
  "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
  "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
  "requestId": "6e865d96-ef8b-408e-a905-5393b4adcfdc",
  "date": "2020-05-16T20:20:15.000Z",
  "body": "{\"code\":\"Authorization_RequestDenied\",\"message\":\"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.\",\"innerError\":{\"request-id\":\"6e865d96-ef8b-408e-a905-5393b4adcfdc\",\"date\":\"2020-05-17T06:20:15\"}}"
}
```

**What I've Tried**

To create the code, I used the following API reference instructions:

- [Create group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-groups?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript)
- [Group properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/group?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties)

Sign-in/sign-out and all other API requests are working.

**Subscription**

```
Microsoft 365 Business Standard Trial
```

**API Permissions**

[image]

```
Directory.AccessAsUser.All +++
Directory.ReadWrite.All ***
Group.ReadWrite.All  
GroupMember.ReadWrite.All ***
openid
profile
Sites.Read.All
Tasks.ReadWrite
User.Read
```

*** I added these after reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60777953), but still get the same error.
+++ I added this after suggestion in answer below.

I have clicked the 'Grant admin consent' button in Azure app registrations area.

**index.html**

```html
<!-- msal -->
<!-- from:  https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-core -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://alcdn.msauth.net/lib/1.3.0/js/msal.js" integrity="****" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- javascript sdk -->
<!-- from:  https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/lib/graph-js-sdk.js"></script>
```

**config.js**

```js
// msal options
const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: "client-id-here",
        redirectUri: "http://localhost:8080",
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant-id-here"
    },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: "sessionStorage",
    storeAuthStateInCookie: false,
    forceRefresh: false
  }
};

// define application permissions   
const scopes = ['directory.accessasuser.all', 'directory.readwrite.all', 'group.readwrite.all', 'groupmember.readwrite.all', 'openid', 'profile', 'sites.read.all', 'user.read', 'tasks.readwrite' ];
```

**auth.js**

```js
const msalApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);

const loginRequest = {
    scopes: scopes
}

async function sign_in() {
    try {
        await msalApplication.loginPopup(loginRequest);
        if (msalApplication.getAccount()) {
            console.log("sign in success");
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("sign in error");
        console.log(error);
    }
}

function sign_out() {
    msalApplication.logout();
}
```

**graph.js**

```js
var path = "/groups"; 
var group = {
  description: "Here is a description.",
  displayName: "test_test_test",
  groupTypes: [
    "Unified",
    "DynamicMembership"
  ],
  mailEnabled: true,
  mailNickname: "test_test_test",
  securityEnabled: false, // initially i had this as true, doesn't seem to make a difference either way  
  visibility: "Hiddenmembership",
  "owners@odata.bind": [
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/my-user-id-here"
  ],
    "members@odata.bind": [
        "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/my-user-id-here"
  ]
};

var response = await client.api(path)
                            .post(group);
```

*Related reading:*

[Compare groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/create-groups/compare-groups?view=o365-worldwide)

[Learn about Microsoft 365 Groups](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/learn-about-microsoft-365-groups-b565caa1-5c40-40ef-9915-60fdb2d97fa2?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB)

[Overview of Microsoft 365 Groups for administrators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/create-groups/office-365-groups?view=o365-worldwide)

[Working with groups in Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/groups-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0)

[Create, edit, or delete a security group in the Microsoft 365 admin center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/email/create-edit-or-delete-a-security-group?view=o365-worldwide)

[Creating teams and managing members using Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-create-group-and-team)

[Overview of Office 365 groups in Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/office365-groups-concept-overview)

***Other ideas about what could be causing error...***

> Visibility is supported only for unified groups; it is not supported for security groups.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/group?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties)

*Maybe the combination of `securityEnabled: true` and `visibility:Hiddenmembership` are not compatible?*

I tried changing it to `securityEnabled: false` and got the same message.

*Is there something wrong with the token?*

I copied the `Authorisation: Bearer` value from Chrome dev tools console and pasted at https://jwt.io and there were *two additional* scopes provided in the token - but all other scopes are present:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it asking for approval by the admin of your Azure ad tenant? I was not able to use user.read.all permission until it was approved by the admin. Also, this works in a daemon app where there is no user.

Comment: I have clicked the 'Grant admin consent' button in Azure app registrations area (added this information to post).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create a `Group` by changing the following in `graph.js`:

```
groupTypes: ["Unified","DynamicMembership"]
```

to

```
groupTypes: ["Unified"]`
```

I have no idea why `DynamicMembership` causes an error.

It is a valid property value of `Group` > `groupTypes` listed at the link below with no caveats:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/group?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties

For reference, the code above creates:

- Group
- SharePoint 'Team Site'
- Outlook email group

It does not automatically create a corresponding:

- Team
- Plan

You can see the new group listed in the following locations:

https://admin.microsoft.com/AdminPortal/Home#/groups

https://outlook.office365.com/people

https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/GroupsManagementMenuBlade/AllGroups

And you can see the group 'Team Site' listed at:

```
https://your_account-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/online/AdminHome.aspx#/siteManagement
```

Answer (score 1):

from your graph call, I saw you try to create the dynamic group and assign a member to this group, the dynamic group did not support to add members, that's the reason why you delete `"dynamicMemberShip`" under group type can fix this issue, below is the example to create dynamic groups via graph API call:

```
{
    "description": "test1",
    "displayName": "test1",
    "groupTypes": [
        "Unified",
        "DynamicMembership"
    ],
    "mailEnabled": true,
    "membershipRule": "user.displayname -contains A",
    "membershipRuleProcessingState":"On",
    "mailNickname": "library",
    "securityEnabled": false,
}
```

Comment: oh, I had a different understanding of what a Dynamic Group was, based on something I read somewhere else, this seems to be a good explanation though:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/dynamic-memberships  So the reason explained in your answer is why I got that specific ‘Insufficient privileges’ error?

Comment: yes, this answer can explain why you got the specific "Insufficient privileges" error and the correct format to create a dynamic group via graph API call

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you have not given **Group.Create** permission in your permission set. 
Give this permission to create a group.

For ***Application permission type***, these all permissions are required:

- Group.Create
- Group.ReadWrite.All
- Directory.ReadWrite.All

And for ***Delegated user permission type***:

- Group.ReadWrite.All
- Directory.ReadWrite.All
- Directory.AccessAsUser.All

Comment: Permissions are `delegated`, not `application`, i have added this detail to the question, thank you.  I only see two permissions in `Microsoft Graph` > `Delegated permissions` > `Group` area:  `Group.Read.All` and `Group.ReadWrite.All`, there is no `Group.Create`.  I tried adding `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` in app and azure and get same error.

Comment: did you mean i have to add `Application` *and* `Delegated` permissions?   I thought I just needed to add `Delegated` permissions for my scenario.

Comment: It should work only with delegated permissions, there's no need to add application permissions, have you specified permissions on Azure portal?

Comment: Are you passing client-secret to get the auth token? @user1063287

Comment: Yes, have specified permissions in azure and app code.  All the authentication is taken care of with MSAL and the javascript SDK, login/logout and other requests are working fine.